# href is not working when I try to send email using native email client in android

Tags: java, android, html, email

Well here is a issue I am using href to give a link in my email body which works fine if I use gmail client but if I use native email client then it does not make it a link it shows me as a plain text. following is the code chunk that i am using .

```
String format="<a href=%s>Link1</a><br>Some Info %s <br> OR dial %s number %s";
String msg = String.format(format, url,info, number,
                    pin);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(msg));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Send mail..."));
```

Can anyone help in this couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add quotes around the `href` value. Browsers probably add them automatically but the native email client does not.

Maybe you can try this:

```
String format="<a href='%s'>Link1</a><br>Some Info %s <br> OR dial %s number %s";
```

I'm not a Java developer so you might know a better way to surround it with quotes.